# The implementation of the DrawerLayout inside the fragment has problems

Tags: kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-navigation

#### Description of the problem

This is my `fragment_hall`:[image]

By clicking on a table, with the Navigation Component I navigate to the `fragment_table_details`:[image]

So far so good but if I now try to navigate back by pressing the back arrow in the toolbar, it does not navigate back but instead opens the drawer:
[image]

The behavior I expect is obviously to return to the `fragment_hall`.

#### Project description

This project has a single activity where, thanks again to the navigation component and then a main_nav_graph, I can navigate between `fragment_login` and `fragment_home`.

Inside the fragment_home I have the `home_nav_graph` in which I can navigate with the drawer layout as seen before.

#### Il codice di `fragment_home`

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentHomeBinding
        get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val activity = (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity)

        val toolbar = binding.toolbar
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val navView = binding.navView

        val navHostFragment =
            childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout

        //Destinazioni possibili raggiungibili dal menu drawer
        val topDestinations = setOf<Int>(
            R.id.homeFragment
        )
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(topDestinations, drawerLayout)

        activity.setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        //Quando si fa swipe per tornare indietro,
        //se il drawer è aperto, lo chiude altrimenti esce dall'app
        activity.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner,
            object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    if (binding.drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                        binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                    } else {
                        activity.finish()
                    }
                }

            })

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            activity,
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_closed
        )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

How can I solve this 'simple' navigation problem?

P.S. If in the fragment_table_details I make a swipe to go back, the behavior is what I expected.